# Find and Replace Macro for translations

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I am trying to modify a Find and Replace macro to translate words based off of ranges.  The two ranges I call out are Column C(Chinese characters) and Column A(English translations) and I keep getting a Run-time error 9 anytime I run the below code:

```
Sub Translate()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Sheets("Translation Sheet").Range("C3:C267").Value2
rplcList = Sheets("Translation Sheet").Range("A3:A267").Value2

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

When I open the debugger the arrow is pointing to the `SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False` line of code.

To answer a few questions that may come up:

The 'Translation Sheet' sheet is in the workbook I am trying to translate and the workbook that the macro is housed in.

I used .Value2 to pull the exact cell contents to avoid any formatting issues.

There are no blanks in the arrays that I defined.

My questions are:

Can a macro be used to translate using find and replace?

What could be the problem is that's causing the error?

Comment: not your problem but I would loop the shts first then the array, it will be quicker.

Comment: BTW you are using a 2D array so:         `sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x,1), Replacement:=rplcList(x,1), _`

Comment: Also, when looping through each worksheet, it looks like you'll probably want to skip `Translation Sheet`.

Comment: Thanks Scott, changing the arrays to the two coordinates fixed the problem, runs as expected now.